# How can i disable Magento module at run time?

Tags: magento-1.7, module

I am using custom checkout module. When user selects a specific category I would like to use default checkout module.

Is it possible to run two checkout engines.

Comment: is event occur on this category visit or this category product cart??

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea.
Have the 2 modules on separate urls and then do a check in the controller to see on which url you should go.

Something like (put this in a helper):

```
public function canUseExtensionCheckout() {
    if (confition for extension use) {
         return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then in the extension controller add this:

```
if (!Mage::helper('some_helper')->canUseExtensionCheckout()) {
    $this->_redirect(default checkout url)
}
```

and in the default checkout controller:

```
if (Mage::helper('some_helper')->canUseExtensionCheckout()) {
    $this->_redirect(extension checkout url)
}
```